# Symfony 4 Entity datetime field returns current date instead of database

Tags: php, symfony

**Symfony 4 Entity datetime field returns current date instead of database.**
I have an Entity image that stores the date of update in a field called updatedAt.

```
    <?php /** @noinspection PhpFullyQualifiedNameUsageInspection */

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ImageRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var File
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="images", fileNameProperty="name")
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)"
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="images", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile(?File $file = null): void
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        if ($file !== null) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
        }
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

But when I retrieve it from the database, the updatedAt field shows the current datatime as bellow:

```
Image {#646 ▼
  -id: 27
  -file: File {#698 ▶}
  -name: "kPRHHeCVrT.jpg"
  -updatedAt: DateTime @1558609804 {#706 ▼
    date: 2019-05-23 11:10:04.486082 UTC (+00:00)
  }
  -tags: PersistentCollection {#686 ▶}
}
```

and a `var_dump($this->updatedAt)` in the getUpdatedAt method shows this:

```
object(DateTime)#626 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-05-19 21:17:48.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } 

object(DateTime)#680 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-05-23 11:24:12.746548" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

note the 2 different objects. I don't understand why it does so.

Comment: Can you show how you set the date ? Because it seems like your are keeping your default value for your date

Comment: the code for the setter is above.

Comment: And all you are doing is a simple $imageRepo->find($id) immediately followed by dump($image) ?  Sure seems like you are newing the image somewhere or maybe you have some custom doctrine event listener plugged in. (Off-topic but the [Symfony dump function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) is generally better than the built in php var_dump function).

Comment: Yeah i tried the built in dump function and it prints the same result. but anyway, I am retrieving the object using the ParameterConverter, also with the findAll function. I am using VichUploader parametered with CurrentDateTimeDirectoryNamer:
directory_namer:
                service: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\CurrentDateTimeDirectoryNamer
                options:
                    date_time_format: 'Y/d/m' 
                    date_time_property: uploadTimestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments in your code states (as you kept it from the official VichUploaderBundle's [documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md)) :

```
public function setFile(?File $file = null): void
{
    $this->file = $file;
    if ($file !== null) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

So this means that everytime you call your **setFile()** method, you will assign the current date to your **$this->updatedAt** property. The Method is called everytime you create/update an Image Object, so it will always hold the current date. **This could also happend because of the inject_on_load parameter set to true in the vich config yaml file.**

I suggest that you **add a new property called vichUpdatedAt()** and use it instead of updatedAt() :

- vichUpdatedAt will be used by the bundle.
- updatedAt will be used by everything else.

**BONUS:** I encourage you to install these extensions : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html
It will allow you to add udpatedAt & createdAt properties easely anywhere you like.

Activate the extension you want (**in /config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml**), so for us right now that would be the timestampable one :

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
```

Then in your image class, just add :

```
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
class Image {
   use TimestampableEntity;
   ....
}
```

And there you go, free updatedAt & createdAt properties, nothing else to do, its just working.

Comment: I was using the same logic in another project, and i just did the same thing that i did before. It must be something that we're missing, also note the new DateTime() in the construtor i was doing that from dacates.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that the main problem is that the bundle is unable to show the asset as it's saved using the currentDateDirectoryNamer wich of course will use the current date not the updatedAt, and so i dont get the asset

Comment: @SalimBenAissa Are you using inject_on_load: true ?  (in vich_uploader.yaml)

Comment: Indid yes and changing it to false solved the problem. But i can't access the file from the object no more, i think the best option is i follow ur demarch or i just remove update in the setFile as i won't change the file usually but i rather remove it and upload another.

Comment: instead you could load your image manually in a service called by your controller, if you have inject_on_load set to false, but yea thats more work to do !

Comment: @SalimBenAissa  the question normally if inject_on_load is enabled setFile() should be called on update or create not on get method. So the question why setFile is called ?